# PHP: Set table cell background based on result

Tags: php, html-table

I'm trying to generate colours based on output of a csv (originally formatted ping).

I can get the values no problem,but the if, ifelse, else doesn't seem to be working.

```
if($min > 0.499 && $min <= 1) {$tcolor = $yellow;} elseif($min >= 1.0) {$tcolor = $red; } else { $tcolor = $white;}
if($avg > 0.499 && $avg <= 1) {$tcolor = $yellow;} elseif($avg >= 1.0) {$tcolor = $red; } else { $tcolor = $white;}
if($max > 0.499 && $max <= 1) {$tcolor = $yellow;} elseif($max >= 1.0) {$tcolor = $red; } else { $tcolor = $white;}
if($mdev > 0.499 && $mdev <= 1) {$tcolor = $yellow;} elseif($mdev >= 1) {$tcolor = $red; } else { $tcolor = $white;}

echo "<tr><td>$ip</td><td bgcolor=\"$tcolor\">$min<br>$tcolor</td><td bgcolor=\"$tcolor\">$avg<br>$tcolor</td><td bgcolor=\"$tcolor\">$max<br>$tcolor</td><td bgcolor=\"$tcolor\">$mdev</td></tr>";
```

Edit: As many asked about the colour code already, I have it above the code listed as

```
$yellow = "#FFFF66";
$red = "#FF0000";
$white = "#FFFFFF";
```

And the number I see the overlap, but I've also tried with 0.999 with the same result.

Comment: Care to post the output as well? I mean you don't share what, say, `$yellow` is

Comment: your conditions overlap: `$min <= 1` and `$min >= 1.0` - both allow for `$min == 1`. plus you're setting the SAME variables in all four conditinos, so basically the last matched condition is the one that'll set the color.

Comment: What is contained in $yellow, $read and $white? The color values should start with a `#`. Furthermore, you should use CSS styles instead of the `bgcolor` attribute: `style="background-color:#abcdef;"`

Comment: It also looks like you are trying to set different colors for each column yet you are using the same color variable `$tcolor` you will want to set them like `$min_color`, `$avg_color` ...

Comment: Marc B, Looks like the issue was the same variable... well the main issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you got it solved, but you should look at using functions like so, so you don't have to repeat if statements like you did.

```
<?php

    function setCellColor($value){

        $color = '#FFFFFF';

        if($value >= 0.5 && $value <= 1){
            $color = '#FFFF00';
        } else if($value > 1) {
            $color = '#FF0000';
        }

        return ' style="background: ' . $color . '" ';
    }

    echo '<tr><td>' . $ip . '</td><td ' . setCellColor($min) . '>' . $min . '</td><td ' . setCellColor($avg) . '>' . $avg . '</td><td ' . setCellColor($max) . '>' . $max . '</td><td ' . setCellColor($mdev) . '>' . $mdev . '</td></tr>';

?>
```

Comment: I would consider using CSS class also... easy to maintain.

Comment: I defiantly agree with @DavidBélanger on that and updating the code above to support that would be very easy to do

Comment: Sweet! Errors on the var and the second colour though. Removing the var and adding a zero to FF000 fixes that.

Comment: @ConfusedHelpdesker thanks for debugging it! I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
function build_td_with_style($value) {
    switch (true) {
        case $value > 0.5 && $value <= 1 :
            $class = 'yellow';
            break;
        case $value > 1 :
            $class = 'red';
            break;
        default : 
            $class = 'white';
    }

    return "<td class='{$class}'>{$value}</td>";
}

$tds = implode('', array_map("build_td_with_style", [$min, $avg, $max, $mdev]));

echo "<tr><td>{$ip}</td>{$tds}</tr>";
```

style.css :

```
   .yellow {
       background-color: yellow;
   }
   .red {
       background-color: red;
   }
   .white {
       background-color: white;
   }
```